# How can we determine if a given Floquet Hamiltonian has time-reversal symmetry?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry, floquet-theory

In quantum mechanics, time reversal takes the form of an anti-unitary operator such that we preserve the canonical commutation relations. We can assign relations for each of the measurables like p and x etc.

However, how does time reversal work when we have a Hamiltonian like
$H(t)=H_0 + V(t)?$
The first part is symmetric under time reversal and $V(t)$ is periodic in $T$. I.e is $\cos(t)$ symmetric under time reversal?

Is it as simple as $t \rightarrow -t,$ why or why not?